# jscolor does not work in a bootstrap modal

Tags: html, colors, safari, modal-dialog, jscolor

I'm trying to make a modal where the color input uses jscolor (because `<input type="color">` doesn't work on safari). But it seems that it doesn't work when I call the next lines, inside the `<div>` of a bootstrap modal.

```
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>
<h2>Example 1</h2>
Color: <input class="jscolor" type="color" value="#563d7c" id="colorTexto" name="colorTexto">
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to Bootstrap's modal has z-index of 1050 but jscolor popup's z-index is 1000 (by default). You have 2 options.

**1. Overwrite value from option parameter**

```
var options = {
    zIndex: 1080
}
var picker = new jscolor('colorTexto', options);
```

**2. Set default z-index value in jscolor.js**

```
(ver 2.0.5 line 1029) 
this.zIndex = 1080;
```

I don't think setting it 9999 is a good idea as it might affect other plug ins.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and this question. I had the exact same problem with the bootstrap-colorpicker and could solve it with this  answer, by setting the zIndex.
$('.colorpicker.dropdown-menu')[0].style.zIndex = "1080";